# Where to find my DB in my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have a problem with my App.
In the update I'm testing I'm modifying the DB adding a column to a table.
Everything works just fine in the simulator, but when I run the App in my iPhone, at the moment it reaches the query where the new column is, it completely skips the while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) and returns no rows to my tableview.

I want to check if the DB in my iPhone has been updated correctly but I don't know where to find it.

Comment: are you testing it on the simulator or the device?

Comment: Try to delete app from device and run again,it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the DB,On your device follow this steps

1.Go to organize window of your x-code.

2.There you can find a option name as device on the top bar.

3.ClIck on device your connected device has greens button side.

4.Click on your device,go to application there you can see a folder as Document.On the folder your DB reside.Download your DB and test.

Answer (score 0):

Well exactly where the DB is depends on where you put it.  However all app files are stored within this folder when using the simulator, so it will be somewhere in here -

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

You can access this by going to 'Go', then 'Go To Folder', from the menu bar in OSX

Comment: And if on the device, use the Organizer to download your app data to your computer.

Comment: -1 for giving info for simulator. Whereas question is being asked for device.

Comment: My bad.  Though still useful to know, as it would help to compare the working - simulator, with the not working - device in order to debug this issue.